# Avoid getting each value of the result into each array when used preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

am new to PHP and am trying to get the data between two tags from a HTML file using `preg_match`, 
ok i got the data but the problem here is each value obtained is coming into each array, like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Bachelors degree
)
Array
(
    [0] => Johny
)
Array
(
    [0] => bsc
)
Array
(
    [0] => java
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1year
)
```

and this is the code i wrote to get the data...

```
$data=file_get_contents($dest); //$dest is the file name
$convert=explode("\n",$data);
foreach($convert as $key=>$value)
{
$output1=preg_match('/^.*<span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:18px; color:#555555;">.*$/',$value,$match1);
if($output1)
{
print_r($match1);
}
}
```

Actually what i want now is, i want to get all the data in a single array.. i.e.,

```
array(
[0] =>  Bachelors degree
[1] => Johny
[2] => bsc
[3] => java
[4] => 1year
)
```

I've googled it and also searched in stackoverflow for the solution but cannot find any... can some one help me / give me a suggestion how to do this ?
Thank you..

Comment: `print_r(array_column($match1, 0));` if you're using PHP >= 5.5. `print_r(array_map($match1, function ($value) { return $value[0]; } );` will work with earlier versions

Comment: Hiii @Mark Baker... am using version 5.2 at present and so i cannot use array_column... but when i used the other one, its showing an error...

Comment: Yes, the several years officially dead PHP 5.2 doesn't support closures.... I'd strongly recommend to a version of PHP that is supported (at least PHP 5.4 because even that will be end of life this year)

Comment: `function flatten ($value) { return $value[0]; } print_r(array_map($match1, 'flatten' ));` If your PHP doesn't support closures

Comment: Hi Mark Baker... thanks for ur answer... i think i've to update the version now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I am assuming, your names are in the span tags. Here is an example data:

```
//$data = file_get_contents($dest); //$dest is the file name
$data = '<span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:18px; color:#555555;">Bachelors degree</span>' . "\n";
$data .= '<span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:18px; color:#555555;">Johny</span>' . "\n";
$data .= '<span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:18px; color:#555555;">bsc</span>' . "\n";
$data .= '<span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:18px; color:#555555;">Java</span>' . "\n";
$data .= '<span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:18px; color:#555555;">1 year</span>' . "\n";
$convert = explode("\n", $data);
$newArray = array();
foreach ($convert as $key => $value) {
    $output1 = preg_match('/^.*<span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:18px; color:#555555;">(.*)<\/span>$/', $value, $match1);

    if ($output1) {
        $newArray[] = $match1[1];
    }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

The output is:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'Bachelors degree' (length=16)
  1 => string 'Johny' (length=5)
  2 => string 'bsc' (length=3)
  3 => string 'Java' (length=4)
  4 => string '1 year' (length=6)
```

UPDATE2:

```
$value = '<p style="color:#555555;"> '."\n".' Html, css, photoshop, javascript,jquery, dreamwaver.. '."\n".' </p>';
preg_match('/<p style="color:#555555;">\s(.*)<\/p>/sm',$value,$match2);
var_dump($match2);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '<p style="color:#555555;"> 
 Html, css, photoshop, javascript,jquery, dreamwaver.. 
 </p>' (length=89)
  1 => string '
 Html, css, photoshop, javascript,jquery, dreamwaver.. 
 ' (length=58)
```

The `s` modifier is your friend.

Comment: Hi lolka bolka... it's not working like this... if i remove the line `$newArray = array();` then its working but its coming as
array(0=>data1)
array(0=>data1,1=>data2)
array(0=>data1,1=>data2,3=>data3)
.
.
.

Comment: and can u do me one more favour... can you tell me how to match NEXT LINE in `preg_match`

Comment: am trying with `/s` but it's not working... is there any other procedure to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean. next line? You can read here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php There is a really good tool for windows, called regex coach to test your patterns.

Comment: Fur suppose i've data like this..
`<p style="color:#555555;"> \n
Html, css, photoshop, javascript,jquery, dreamwaver.. \n
</p>`

and am dng this.. 
`preg_match('/<p style="color:#555555;">\s(.*)<\/p>/',$value,$match2);`

but its not displaying any data... what's wrong in that line ??

Comment: Hiii @Lolka Bolka... do u know what's wrong in this regexp ??

Comment: Hii thanks for ur answer, but it's working for this... but not working on my data... actually the place where i kept `\n` is the new line in my data... is that the reason why it's not working ??


`<p style="color:#555555;"> {NEW LINE HERE}
{TAB SPACES HERE}      Html, css, photoshop, javascript,jquery, dreamwaver..{TAB SPACES HERE}     </p>`

Comment: I think this should be a new question. It's hard to discuss here, what do you want, and what is the solution for that.

Comment: hmm ok i'll post a new question then..  actually the regexp is not matching my data/not showing the results... that's my problem